# Issue with knockout custom binding callback function parameter name bindingContext

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js. I am trying to create a confirmation dialog through custom binding.
I have an array `people`. Through `foreach` binding i am displaying each entry of array with a delete link associated with each item. When user click over the delete link the confirm dialog open to make sure whether user wants to delete it or not. To show the confirm dialog i am using custom binding name `confirm`. Whenever user click over the delete button, the confirmMessageText (associated observable with element) value changed so `confirm` binding update function calls. From this function user can delete the item on the basis of confirm dialog decision. I have created a *FIDDLE EXAMPLE* also :

http://jsbin.com/ocakap/4/edit

**My problem** : I am facing a problem with custom binding update callback function parameter name `bindingContext`. Through this i am accessing the knockout special property name `$data` but for each entry the `$data` contains the last element object of the array (*In my fiddle example case it is Denise*. *You can see this by click over any delete link, an alert occurs shows the value of $data parameter* ).

How can i solve this issue, how will i get the current element object entry of the array in the update callback function ?

Answer (score 1):

In the click binding you update the confirmation message that force the knockout to check all dependencies and in this case KO runs confirm binding 3 times and the last item for which dialog appears is the last person in the array.

To fix this, you need to introduce a variable that will hold the person object that you want to delete.

Here is working fix http://jsbin.com/ocakap/12/edit.